# Barcode security with own developed software

Tags: c++, security, barcode

I am making an application to secure barcodes so the patients at hospitals cant read them. But i want to hear your perspective on it.

First of all im making this program in C++.

My idea is to make a barcode and secure it for patients at hospital for a application which i am developing (secret sorry guys).

The way i am going to secure it is to get the following information about the patients.

- Their unique ID nr (its possible in Denmark to do that)
- Their room nr which they are staying at
- Their Patient nr (the patients have a specific patient number)

The unique ID nr is containing 10 chars. The room nr contains 2 digits and the Patient nr contain 10 digits.

If I am predefining each chars and digits to random numbers and letters, and if I for example take 1 char from the ID nr and generate it to 5 chars in my secured code (or maybe after I have generated the new code I will secure it afterwards with a AES code or something), would that be a good way to secure the barcode, so the patient cant read the BarCode and get information of it?

The problem is that the patient must not scan the other patients barcode and retrieve information out of it, because that will be a big problem.

Comment: The first and most basic assumption of security is that your algorithm is known to the attacker (or in this case, the patient in the next room with his mighty smartphone).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please *don't* do what you are suggesting!

Instead, use a surrogate key (barcode) which is held securely in a database (and by that, I mean carefully check all relevant laws in your jurisdiction).

Don't try and be clever and 'encrypt' any info into the key. It will come back to bite you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to look into that.

Comment: Correct. Take your attacker scenario, an intruder with a barcode scanner. He just gets a random string, and the only thing he can observe is that it's a different string for each patient. A side benefit is that it's way easier to update a room number in the database when a patient moves. BTW, there's a good chance that the hospital already has such a database.